# Error when using CDN for jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cdn

Probably something obvious but I'm very new to jQuery and ajax overall. Environment - ASP.NET

I referenced jQuery like so:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.1/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

When I start web project I get error popup:

```
Unhandled exception at line 4, column 10920 in http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: img["data-over"]:eq(0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're seeing that in Visual Studio, correct? I'd `continue` in the dialog and see if the browser blows up (`F12` gets you dev console in IE). Visual Studio catches on a lot of JS exceptions the browsers ignore. Chances are the browser is just fine and VS is being overly sensitive.

Comment: Everyone has their own favored method of debugging, but I'll almost guarantee that if you become competent with the debugging tools in browsers (`F12` in IE, `Ctrl+Shift+J` in Chrome, `Firebug` extension in Firefox) you'll enjoy JS development a whole lot more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-over` is the property; it's the value, if you have one, that gets put in quotes.

`$('img[data-over]:eq(0)')`

vs.

`$('img[data-over="somevalue"]:eq(0)')`

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjNw6/) for a demo.